# The HTTP method is not allowed for the specified URL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We would like to use PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods when building our internal API in Domino, but I can't configure those methods. Server refusing to pass them.

When I used method PUT Domino replied to me:

> Error code: 405 | Request method is not allowed by the server

After that I enabled methods via notes.ini

```
HTTPEnableMethods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,PATCH
```

That seems to help a bit but now it says something about URL, but I do not really get what it means.

> Error code: 405 | The HTTP method is not allowed for the specified URL

I have made tests on two different setups: with and without internet sites documents enabled in server documents.

---

Does anybody what I need to do to solve the problem above?

---

**UPDATE**

I just noticed a help text on Internet Site for "Methods" field.

> GET, HEAD, and POST are the most commonly used methods. OPTIONS and TRACE are useful for debugging. PUT and DELETE should only be enabled if the Web site includes special CGI programs or Java applications that implement them.

Based on that it seems it is not possible to make PUT and DELETE work out of the box.

Comment: Did you enable PUT, PATCH and DELETE in the internet site document?

Comment: @perHenrikLausten yes, I did.

Comment: Good, just wanted to make sure

Comment: The method (PUT) is not allowed for this URL - what is the URL?  The end point may not be PUT-able.

Comment: @teleman it's URL that points to an agent.

Comment: Only GET and POST for a Notes agent would be possible.